# What's the name of this kinda graphic design

Tags: texture, style-identification

Saw this texture on a book in Amazon. Also twitter used this kinda texture on their designes. Wonder if there is specific name for it?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. These appear to be simple scans/photographs of real objects which have been scratched/worn, then used as a background, and possibly overlaid with new elements.

Comment: The first image's texture looks more like a hard floor's texture. The second's texture resembles more of a wall with less direct contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not anything really "official" -- but most often it's referred to as "**distressed**" or occasionally "**grunge**".

Comment: "Scratched" describes the second one also